# Python Regex Replace Unless

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, replace

Is there some sort of re.sub_unless function?  I can't seem to find one.

So I'm trying to format punctuation (in HTML documents) using regex in Python.  In stripping unneeded spaces before punctuation at the end of a paragraph, I keep running into the problem of emoticons.  So, for instance

```
"text - </p>"
```

and

```
"text . ) </p>"
```

should render to

```
"text-</p>"
```

and

```
"text.)</p>",
```

but

```
"text :)</p>"
```

shouldn't render to

```
"text:)</p>".
```

Writing a regular expression to match

```
" [emoticon]</p>"
```

wouldn't be difficult, so if there was some re.sub_unless(pattern, unless_pattern, text) function, that would be perfect for my needs.

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead.

Comment: You need to build an alternation-based regex capturing one of its parts. Then use a callback method/lambda expression to implement the replacement logic.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't a re.sub_unless, you could do the following,

```
    import re
    # text = "text :)</p>"
    text = "text . ) </p>"
    result = text
    if ":)" not in text:
      result = re.sub('\s*', "", text)
```

If you have more than one emoji you could do the following,

```
import re
# text = "text :)</p>"
text = "text . ) </p>"
result = ""

emojis = [":)", ":("]

for emoji in emojis:
  if emoji in text:
    result = text
    break
  result = re.sub('\s*', "", text)


print(result)
```

Not the most performat code but does the job.